# How to create a multiline UITextfield?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

I am developing an application where user has to write some information. For this purpose I need a `UITextField` which is multi-line (in general `UITextField` is a single line).

As I'm Googling I find a answer of using `UITextView` instead of `UITextfield` for this purpose.

Comment: Here is the small control I wrote exactly for that purpose.
it has multiline support and also Done button for closing keyboard.
feel free to use it https://code.google.com/p/galtextfield/

Comment: use this third party classes import your xcode project and use it, its working too good link :https://github.com/adonoho/HPGrowingTextView

Answer (score 496, accepted):

`UITextField` is specifically one-line only.

Your Google search is correct, you need to use `UITextView` instead of `UITextField` for display and editing of multiline text.

In Interface Builder, add a `UITextView` where you want it and select the "editable" box.  It will be multiline by default.

Comment: So tell me please how native Calendar app makes View with placeholder and word wrap for notes at event adding screen ?

Comment: how to set placeholder for UITextView?

Comment: You can't add placeholder to TextView, but you can add a gray label over TextView, and hide it if user input some text.

Comment: Please can anybody help me with the following question? If the user writes bulleted text (multiple line breaks) in UITextView, how to detect the total number of line breaks?

Comment: @Markus you should open a new question for that

Answer (score 35):

You can fake a UITextField using UITextView. The problem you'll have is that you lose the place holder functionality.

**If you choose to use a UITextView and need the placeholder, do this:**

In your viewDidLoad set the color and text to placeholders:

```
myTxtView.textColor = .lightGray
myTxtView.text = "Type your thoughts here..."
```

Then make the placeholder disappear when your UITextView is selected:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing (textView: UITextView) {
    if myTxtView.textColor.textColor == ph_TextColor && myTxtView.isFirstResponder() {
        myTxtView.text = nil
        myTxtView.textColor = .white
    }
}
```

When the user finishes editing, ensure there's a value. If there isn't, add the placeholder again:

```
func textViewDidEndEditing (textView: UITextView) {
    if myTxtView.text.isEmpty || myTxtView.text == "" {
        myTxtView.textColor = .lightGray
        myTxtView.text = "Type your thoughts here..."
    }
}
```

**Other features you might need to fake:**

UITextField's often capitalize every letter, you can add that feature to UITableView:

```
myTxtView.autocapitalizationType = .words
```

UITextField's don't usually scroll:

```
myTxtView.scrollEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 19):

Ok I did it with some trick ;) First build a `UITextField` and increased it's `size` like this :

```
CGRect frameRect = textField.frame;
        frameRect.size.height = 53;
        textField.frame = frameRect;
```

Then build a `UITextView` exactly in the same area that u made my `UITextField`, and deleted its `background color`. Now it looks like that u have a multiple lines `TextField` !

Comment: I used auto layout and pinned all the sides of the UITextField to the UITextView. Really great trick, thanks!

Comment: please @phantmann , can you show us your code for auto layout?

Comment: This creates a `UITextView`. The point of having a UITextField is that it behaves differently than a `UITextView`.

Comment: There are a bunch of differences between `UITextView` and `UITextfield`: they inherit from `UIScrollView` vs `UIControl`, not-editable-by-default vs. editable-by-default, multiline vs. single-line, different delegate protocols, no-placeholder vs. placeholder.

Comment: `UITextView` is for paragraphs of text. Use it if you need a paragraph of text, and not otherwise.

Comment: This hack is useless.

Answer (score 9):

Besides from the multiple line behaviour, the main difference between UITextView and UITextField is that the UITextView does not propose a placeholder. To bypass this limitation, you can use a UITextView with a "fake placeholder."

See this SO question for details: [Placeholder in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a UITextView is what you're looking for. You'll have to deal with some things differently (like the return key) but you can add text to it, and it will allow you to scroll up and down if there's too much text inside.

This link has info about making a screen to enter data:

[create a data entry screen](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-create-a-data-entry-screen)

Answer (score 2):

If you must have a UITextField with 2 lines of text, one option is to add a UILabel as a subview of the UITextField for the second line of text.  I have a UITextField in my app that users often do not realize is editable by tapping, and I wanted to add some small subtitle text that says "Tap to Edit" to the UITextField.

```
CGFloat tapLlblHeight = 10;
UILabel *tapEditLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, textField.frame.size.height - tapLlblHeight - 2, 70, tapLlblHeight)];
tapEditLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tapEditLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
tapEditLbl.text = @"Tap to Edit";

[textField addSubview:tapEditLbl];
```

Answer (score 2):

use UITextView instead of UITextField

Answer (score 2):

```
'override func viewDidLoad(){
super.viwDidLoad()
YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.textColor = UIColor.gray // YOUR PREFERRED PLACEHOLDER COLOR HERE
YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.text =  "YOUR DEFAULT PLACEHOLDER TEXT HERE"
YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.delegate = self
}'
```

This code block is enough. Please don't forget to set delegate in viewDidLoad or by storyboard just before to use the following extension:

```
extension YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER: UITextViewDelegate {
    
    func textViewDidBeginEditing (_ textView: UITextView) {
        if YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.text.isEmpty || YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.text == "YOUR DEFAULT PLACEHOLDER TEXT HERE" {
            YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.text = nil
            YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.textColor = .red // YOUR PREFERED COLOR HERE
        }
    }
    func textViewDidEndEditing (_ textView: UITextView) {
        if YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.text.isEmpty {
            YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.textColor = UIColor.gray // YOUR PREFERED PLACEHOLDER COLOR HERE
            YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.text =  "YOUR DEFAULT PLACEHOLDER TEXT HERE"
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A supplement to h4xxr's answer in the above, an easier way to adjust the height of the UITextField is to select  square border style in the attribute inspectors->Text Field. (By default, the border style of a UITextfield is ellipse.)

Reference: Answered Brian in here : [How to set UITextField height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641557/how-set-uitextfield-height)

Answer (score 0):

Use `textView` instead then conform with its delegate, call the `textViewDidChange` method inside of that method call `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` and don't forget to set `rowHeight` and `estimatedRowHeight` to `UITableView.automaticDimension`.

Answer (score -1):

There is another option that worked for me:

Subclass UITextField and overwrite:

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
```

In this method you can for example:

```
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : self.font,
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName : self.textColor };

    [self.text drawInRect:verticalAlignedRect withAttributes:attributes];
```

This code will render the text using as many lines as required if the rect has enough space. You could specify any other attribute depending on your needs.

Do not use:

```
self.defaultTextAttributes
```

which will force one line text rendering