# How to make UITextField text multiple lines

Tags: iphone, ios4, uikit, uitextfield

In my app, I have a textbox that the user can fill. Most times, this will be quite a lenghty text, I'm using `UITextField` but this does not go to a new line when the user types over the iPhone screen. How do I make it go to the next line?

Comment: Just use a `UITextView`?

Comment: You can make it with some tricks. Please check my answer here : [Multiline UITextfield][1]


  [1]: http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/13476467/1572408

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 Just Go With UITextView instead of UITextField.
```

Comment: But the editing starts from center (vertically). I want it to start from top.

Answer (score 5):

UITextField doesn't provide any option to make it multi-lined text box. So you have to go with UITextView.

In interface builder place an UITextView and connect with an IBOutlet. I am assuming that you know how to do that.

Suppose you connected this UITextView with an IBOutlet named address. So now write the following code on viewDidLoadmethod.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    address.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    [address.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];

    [address.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
    address.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

Now add this line at the beggening of the file to import QuarzCore library

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Now your TextView will look like a TextFiled.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: this is a nice solution - wonder if you can take this further to replicate different border styles seen on textFields

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure , but maybe this could help you :
**- Go to the interface builder**
**- On the text field attributes , change the border to your type**
**- Some border are made so you can change the size and all**

Hope it helps !