# How to create a multi-line UITextField?

Tags: ios

How can I implement a multiple line textfield like what I see in the iPhone messaging application. in other words, How to expand the box dynamically when user press return key or when text run to next line.
I notice this question already been asked at:

[Objective C: How to create a multi-line UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398519/objective-c-how-to-create-a-multi-line-uitextfield)

and the solution was to use UITextView, however, UITextView doesn't look as deli gent as UITextView because it doesn't show border depth as UITextView.

regards,

Comment: I found solution here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398519/objective-c-how-to-create-a-multi-line-uitextfield][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398519/objective-c-how-to-create-a-multi-line-uitextfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use UITextView without border and put some UIImageViews above for your own border.

Comment: i'm new to iOS developemnt, do you have any example that show how to accomplish this.

Comment: cdn.thetechjournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/41417.jpg 
Check the chat box at the bottom of the pic. The white part is your UITextView and the dark gray part is the border which is drawn by some UIImageViews.

Answer (score 0):

You can find my answer for that here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13476467/1572408

hope it help :)