# iOS: Auto expanding Text Field

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

Before marking as duplicate, I want to say that I've read pretty much all the questions about auto expanding `UITextFields`, and how they are actually `UITextViews` instead.

The questions I've read definitely works and I've implemented an auto growing `UITextView` however when I take a good look at the `UITextViews` of **WhatsApp**, **Telegram** and of course the **iOS messaging app** I see that (by appearance) at least they look a lot like regular **UITextFields**. If they are indeed, does anyone know the **exact** **borderColor** and **borderRadius** values.

If they are in fact something different, does anyone know an **updated** autogrowing `UITextField` or `UITextView` tutorial?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398519/objective-c-how-to-create-a-multi-line-uitextfield may be duplicate

Comment: @DaxeshNagar Thanks for the comment. I've checked the question and like I said it does not provide an insight for iOS7 type of UITextField. Thanks

Comment: Kindly Follow the [thread][1] to expand the height of UITextView dynamically.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content