# ios check if text is too big for uiTextfield

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextfield

This question is **not** about UITextView: It's about UITextField.

How do I check if my text would be too long for my UITextField? I need to dynamically change the Height of my UITextField so that it accepts multiple lines. Is this possible or must I use a UITextView for this? I prefer UITextField because of the convenience of a placeholder text.

Comment: Text fields don't accept multiple lines.

Comment: Text can never be too long for a text field, because it scrolls sideways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
sizeWithFont:
```

of NSString to avaluate the length of a string.

UITextField is not able to show multiple lines. For solutions take a look at

[Objective C: How to create a multi-line UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398519/objective-c-how-to-create-a-multi-line-uitextfield)

Claus

Answer (score 0):

Hi just use small trick for this code sample below.

```
+ (CGFloat)expectedHeightWithData:(MECommentData *)data
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSString *comment = data.comment;

        UIFont *commentSizeFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Miso-Bold" size: 15.0];
        CGSize commentSize = [NSString sizeWithFont:commentSizeFont width:225 heitght:3000 text:comment];

        return ceilf(commentSize.height);
    }

}
```