# Storyboard - Position is ambiguous for "Round Style Text Field" Warning

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios7, xcode5, uistoryboard

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16251810/2589276

I solved the problem above but got a new problem when I did the steps I was instructed to.
Now I get a warning saying:

```
Position is ambiguous for "Round Style Text Field"
```

I tried setting fixed constraint for width also, but did not fix this warning.

Any ideas? Are there any other information I should give for this problem?

This screen shot when I do add constraint to x, leading space constraint (for x) and vertical space constraint from the bottom.

[image]

I just want to set constraint for the Y and not get warnings, I do not use autolayout anyways.

Edit:

When I try to add missing constraints, this happens:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With Xcode 5 there is an option to add missing constraints. Pls see the screenshot attached below:

[image]

Comment: I edited the post, showing a screen shot after I did what you told

Comment: The link for Autolayout video is https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?include=409#409.           All 2013 WWDC videos are available in the link: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/