# Xamarin: Set UITextField Height

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uitextfield, xamarin

How do I change the height of a text field in Xamarin iOS?

In native iOS, you can set the height on the UITextField outlet manually, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8641583/1256653), but in Xamarin, it doesn't allow you to change that property. Is this possible in Xamarin using an actual UITextField? If not, what's the nicest hack to get something similar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RectangleF in C# is a struct so you will need to make a copy of it, change the value and set it back to the control.

```
        var f = textField.Frame;

        f.Height = 100f;

        textField.Frame = f;
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried setting the frame like this?

```
textField.Frame = new RectangleF (x, y, width, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

UsernameText.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(UsernameText.Frame.X, UsernameText.Frame.Y,UsernameText.Frame.Width, UsernameText.Frame.Height + 5);