# UITextField Height not changing when set as inputAccessoryView for another UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
var textF2 = UITextField()
textF2.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
textF2.frame.size = CGSizeMake(200, 200)
textF2.text = self.textField.text
textF2.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

self.textField.inputAccessoryView = textF2
```

textF2's height refuses to be set properly, atleast in terms of its appearance.

```
println(textF2.frame.size.height)
```

gives me the new value of 200 however it does not appear in the simulator that way.

Does inputAccessoryView cause problems related to setting the height?

```
var textF2 = UITextField()
textF2.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
textF2.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)
textF2.text = self.textField.text
textF2.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.view.addSubview(textF2)
```

does in fact give me proper appearance, so

```
self.textField.inputAccessoryView = textF2
```

is the problem. Does anybody know why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How set UITextField height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641557/how-set-uitextfield-height)

Comment: No, look at my code, it is different. I apply the same recommendations.

Comment: Does the compiler give you warnings/errors?

Comment: Nope, XCode just writes 200.0 from that println

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Answer (score 1):

`inputAccessoryView` is just a normal `UIView` underneath so to position it correctly you should set the `frame` always, setting only the size will have no effect.

Also, take in mind, that after the object became first responder any changes to the `inputAccessoryView` should be followed by a call to `reloadInputViews` otherwise they will not have any effect.

Comment: Thanks for the `reloadInputViews` reminder.