# unexpected behaivour when changing the height of text field statically

Tags: ios, height, textfield

I am not able to change the height of `UITextField` statically in xCode 6. If I try it in new project than also I am getting same problem. It seems that it is fixed for all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you unchecked autolayout ?

Comment: post some code that you've tried!

Comment: @Bhupesh no idea new to xcode

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati i didn't wrote any code! working on xcode 6! directly drag text feild

Comment: try to change **border style** in attribute Inspector.

Comment: change your textFiled border style to None than increase the height

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati ya that's helpful! but, it's not working when i move back to older border style.

Comment: @Bhupesh same answer as above for you. :)

Comment: Yes It will not increase height in roundedRect style

Comment: @Bhupesh before it was working correctly. Suddenly this situation arises.

Comment: Or you can do like first set your borderstyle to none. then increase height, give border to Your textFiled from layer 

_yourTextField.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    _yourTextField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:231.0/255.0 green:231.0/255.0 blue:231.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
    _yourTextField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake (0.0f, 10.0f);
    _yourTextField.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0f;
    _yourTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;

Comment: @Bhupesh ya got it. thank you buddy for your efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the border style from here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can not change UItextField height if its button style is ***RoundedRect***. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/19002274/244519 for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the height constraint for the textfield :

[image]

Here the height is 30, you may change it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change border style from attribute inspector. as here

[image]