# iOS - how do I make a text field taller than 1 line?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am making my first text field, and I am looking for more of a text area that the person can fill out. Xcode disables for me the ability to extend it to more than one line.  Is it possible? If so, how do I do that?

Thanks![image]

Comment: Please check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13476467/1572408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multiline `UITextField` is implemented by the [`UITextView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) and making sure its `editable` property is set to `YES`.

> The `UITextView` class implements the behavior for a scrollable, multiline text region.

Comment: @EvanMulawski I am looking for the UITextView in my bottom right of the storyboard, but I don't quite see it. How do I get to it? :) Thanks!

Comment: @Genadinik: I assume you mean `UITextView` - it should be labeled Text View. Try changing the selection from "Controls" to "Objects".

Answer (score 2):

You want a `UITextView`, which is an editable field that can accomodate more than one line of text.