# How does the iOS Reminders App allow word wrapping to the next line in the TableView?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am using the iOS Reminders App on my iPhone, and I was noticing that inside the tableview it allows you to enter text that can wrap around to a new line and continue entering text for a reminder. I notice that the height of the cell changes to accommodate the size of the reminder text supplied. My question is I know this could be done with a UILabel, but you can't edit and enter text in a UILabel can you? So it must be a UITextField, but I thought a UITextField didn't allow the words to wrap to a new line? I thought it just continued to shrink itself down on one line? So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried UITextView, it does the auto wrapping for you, but to auto resize the table cell height, might have to use the textViewDelegate didReplaceString method.

```
// goes inside the UITextView didReplaceString method
// assumes expectedTextSize is a CGSize struct (like this CGSize expectedTextSize)
expectedTextSize = [myTextView.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:"Arial" size:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 999999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

// then in your tableView:heightForRow: table view delegate method
return expectedTextSize.height;
```

Comment: I think you might be correct. Thank you very much. This has been tested here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1345724/223480

Answer (score 1):

It most likely uses a `UITextView` which does allow multiple text lines.  You can then change the height of the `UITableViewCell` when the text wraps to the next line by looking at the delegate methods of `UITextView`.

Comment: I didn't see anything in the docs, that suggested a UITextField can have multiple lines of text, but thanks I guess I just missed it?