# how to create a multiline UITextfield with multiple placeholders programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

how to create a multiline UITextfield programmatically?

I need to create a multiline supporting textfield which has multiple placeholders. I don't wish to refer to its xib.

Comment: for that, you have `UITextView`.

Comment: Use UITextView for multiline text entry, but I don't think multiple placeholders are possible.

Comment: By saying: `I don't wish to refer to its xib.` What do you exactly mean?

Comment: Think he wants to create it programmatically and not in a xib file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it with some tricks. Please check my answer here : [Multiline UITextfield](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/13476467/1572408)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear, so this might be the answer:

```
UITextView *textView ;
textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 50)] ;

NSString *myMultilineString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"nanan %d \nline2 %f\nline3 %@", 5, 1.45f, self] ; 
textView.text = myMultilineString ;
textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO ;

[self.view addSubview:textView] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://github.com/flypigz/UIPlaceHolderTextView
It's a subclass of UITextView where UILabel is added as a placeholder. You can add multiple labels if you need multiple placeholder.