# Textfield's size change when enter large text

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

In my app I have multiple textField. when I enter small text than it will work fine, but when large text is entered than textField size changed.

Like this

With small text

[image]

With large text

[image]

And yes its only happen in iOS6 not in iOS5.

**UPDATE**

I dont know how to but i have change my constraint property in ios6 screen and it will now run fine. Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[yourTextField setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:FALSE];
```

Comment: do you mean that fontsize of the uitexfield is changing i.e. getting smaller..?

Comment: No as you can see if i enter large amount of text than textfield's width also increase. thats i dont want to i want textfield default effect of hiding charecter with ... sign

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one.But `UITextField` doesn't provide any option to make it multi-lined text box. So you have to go with `UITextView`.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    CGSize size = [txtView.text sizeWithFont:txtView.font];
    CGRect f = txtView.frame;
    f.size.height = ceil(size.width/f.size.width)*size.height;
    txtView.frame = f;
}
```

And for more info..

1. [How to create a multiline UITextfield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345561/how-to-create-a-multiline-uitextfield/1345724#1345724)

Otherwise if you don't wanna make in next line then use this code.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(320, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize requiredSize = [textField.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0f] constrainedToSize:boundingSize
                                         lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGFloat requiredHeight = requiredSize.height;

    CGRect frame1;
    frame1 = txtFld.frame;
    frame1.size.height = requiredHeight;
    txtFld.frame = frame1;
    NSLog(@"%f", frame1.size.height);
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to change the width then you can restrict it by `textField.frame.size.width`

property.

that means after extending to some width ,restrict to input

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem too. I had to set the left and right constraint of my text field and its adjacent uilabel to ensure my text field doesn't resize itself after entering large amount of text. This is a issue with Autolayout. Tried all the above solutions, can't be fixed by above solutions.