# Program UITextField to go to next line when 'Return' is pressed?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a UITextField that it set up with autocapitalization, correction, etc., those type of modifiers. I also have a custom toolbar above the keyboard with a "done" button for closing the keyboard.

However, I need the user to be able to enter "returns" in their text for formatting purposes. I have the following code which triggers when the "return" key is pressed:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

However, in this case the return key closes the keyboard. Can someone please tell me how to change this code snippet to instead add a blank line to the growing text the user is entering upon clicking "return"?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you HAVE to use a UITextField? UITextView is better suited for this.

Comment: Please do not use the objective-c tag unless you have questions about the actual programming language (and not for questions about the ios library usage)...

Comment: check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13476467/1572408

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`UITextField` does not support multiline text very well.  To support multiline text you probably want to use `UITextView`