# Making UITextView behave like UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How do I make a UITextView behave like a `UITextField` or maybe how to make a `UITextField` appear like this, same with the photo, i've searched a lot about making `UITextField` into multiple lines but i can't seem to get how they did it, is there any method that is much simpler,

[image]

I also tried putting a `UITextView` and then sending it at back and putting at top a `UITextField` and in the `viewDidLoad` I did `self.commentTextField.frame = self.commentsTextView.frame;` , i thought it would make the `UITextField` like a `UITextView`.
I want that when I start editing this 
`- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textField;`
delegate would detect that Im editing the `UITextField` because I can't seem to detect when Im editing the `UITextView`

Comment: So you are looking for rounded corners, right?

Comment: nop, Im looking for making a UITextField like that in the pic, if its possible though.

Comment: It might be helpful if you tell us why you don't want to use a UITextView.

Comment: I want that when I start editing this `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textField;` delegate would detect that Im editing the `UITextField` because I can't seem to detect when Im editing the `UITextView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others said, use `UITextView` instead of `UITextField`, just remebering of setting `editable` to `YES`.

And about the delegate, `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textField;` is a method of `UITextFieldDelegate` , and, as the name of the protocol says, it will only work for UITextFields. Changing the type of the parameters will have no effect.

What you may want is the similar [`textViewDidBeginEditing:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidBeginEditing%3a) , of `UITextViewDelegate`. Implement this new protocol, just don't forgetting to set the delegate correctly.

```
self.textView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

UITextField is one line only, you need to use UITextView instead, and if you are looking for rounded corners you can use:

```
self.commentTextField.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.commentTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
```

I suggest to check this question:

[How to create a multiline UITextfield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345561/how-to-create-a-multiline-uitextfield)