# Newline and / or Carriage Return in Swift String

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, newline, carriage-return

I am attempting to add a Newline or Carriage return in a UITextView.

```
    var text = UITextField()
    text.text = "This is a text \r\n This is a text"
```

The result shows the entire text on one line:

This is a text This is a text

Is it not possible to do a Newline or CR in a UITextView? Or what am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345561/how-to-create-a-multiline-uitextfield

Comment: Your first line says that you want carriage return in UITextView, but then. the code shows otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UITextField` is generally single-line and does not support multiline text. Use a `UITextView` instead