# How can I get more lines of text in a text field?

Tags: text, swift3, uitextfield

I am coding in swift 3 and I want to type a message in an app but when you type more than the leght of the text field, the beginning of your typing disappears. How can I code that my tekstfield gets multiple lines of text if you type more?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Check this  -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13476467/1572408

Comment: Could you give your code?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Text fields are designed to only have one line.

Replace it with a `UITextView` instead.