# How to style UITextView to like Rounded Rect text field?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am using a text view as a comment composer.

In the properties inspector I can't find anything like a border style property so that I can make use a rounded rect, something like `UITextField`.

So, the question is: How can I style a `UITextView` like a `UITextField` with a rounded rect?

Comment: Could you not use `UITextField` and just turn off `userInteractionEnabled`?

Answer (score 284, accepted):

There is no implicit style that you have to choose, it involves writing a bit of code using the `QuartzCore` framework:

```
//first, you
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

//.....

//Here I add a UITextView in code, it will work if it's added in IB too
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 220, 200, 100)];

//To make the border look very close to a UITextField
[textView.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];
[textView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];

//The rounded corner part, where you specify your view's corner radius:
textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
textView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

It only works on OS 3.0 and above, but I guess now it's the de facto platform anyway.

Comment: I found adding the following top the above code makes the border look very close to a UITextField. [textView.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];
    [textView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];

Comment: Make sure to have: #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> .  I had problems because I didn't import QuartzCore

Comment: For n00bs like me, worthy of note: put this code in viewDidLoad NOT in initWithNibName :-)

Comment: You can just use a `UITextField` with the `borderStyle` property set to `UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect` - see my post below.

Comment: On iOS 7, I find that a border width of 0.5f works much better.

Comment: borderWidth = 0.5f matches perfect in iOS 7

Comment: iOS 7 - borderWidth of 1.0 and alpha of .2 works with the default style.

Comment: what does `textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect` do then? What's the difference between that and your way?

Answer (score 77):

this code worked well for me:

```
    [yourTextView.layer setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [yourTextView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
    [yourTextView.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
    [yourTextView.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
    [yourTextView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: I would say that 5px is closer to text fields, but this answer's gray color is better than the selected answer.

Comment: Of course you need to add QuartzCore Framework for this answer and import it by #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Answer (score 42):

### Swift 3 Version

After setting up the text view in interface builder.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5     
    textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5  
    textView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

### Swift 2.2 Version

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5     
    textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5).CGColor
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5  
    textView.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: Problem is that it's not gray exactly. Color of UITextField's frame is a bit different.

Comment: Making .borderWidth = 0.7 makes it look closer to current style I see on iOS 11.

Comment: Experimented with this a little on iOS14.  It actually seems to render slightly differently depending on the model of phone used and does not look the same on iPhone8 vs iPhone11Pro.  However as with Chris above, I found borderWidth = 0.7 to be good.  In addition I found that colorWithAlphaComponent(0.25) gave a better result

Answer (score 28):

**Edit: You have to import**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

**for using corner radius.**

Try this it will work for sure

```
UITextView* txtView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 100)];
txtView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
txtView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

As 
Rob figured it out setting the if you want the border color to be similar as `UITextField` then you need to change the border width to 2.0 and color to gray by adding the following line

```
[textView.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]]; 
[textView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];
```

Comment: I was wondering why this wasn't working. Thanks for the tipoff about QuartzCore.

Answer (score 23):

I wanted the real deal, so I add `UIImageView` as a subview of the `UITextView`. This matches the native border on a `UITextField`, including the gradient from top to bottom:

```
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImageView *borderView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, textView.frame.size.width, textView.frame.size.height)];
borderView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
UIImage *textFieldImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"TextField.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 8, 15, 8)];
borderView.image = textFieldImage;
[textField addSubview: borderView];
[textField sendSubviewToBack: borderView];
```

These are the images I use:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think you also need to tell the textView to have UITextBorderStyle None if you haven't set that already in XCode

Comment: I re-uploaded the png images

Comment: No good, the background moves as you scroll the UITextView.  Guess I'll have to place it all in a parent UIView.

Answer (score 13):

One solution is to **add a UITextField below the UITextView**, make the `UITextView` background transparent and disable any user interaction on the `UITextField`. Then in code change the `UITextField` frame with something like that

```
self.textField.frame = CGRectInset(self.textView.frame, 0, -2);
```

You will have exactly the same look as a text field.

And as suggested by [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1510181/jon), you should put this piece of code inside `[UIViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]` on iOS 5.0+.

Comment: This was so simple and looks exactly how I wanted it to look. I just matched the frame of the UITextField to the UITextView: 


    CGRect frame = self.myTextView.frame;
    frame.size.height +=2;
    self.myTextField.frame = frame;

Comment: Lovely answer. Clean and simple. Put code in ```viewDidLayoutSubviews:``` (iOS 5.0+).

Comment: Nice, this was the soln I went with in the end. Note that it did not work until I used Jon's comment re: viewDidLayoutSubviews:

Comment: This was the quickest, and looks the best.

Answer (score 5):

For the best effect you have to use a custom (stretchable) background image. This is also how the `UITextField`'s rounded border is drawn.

Answer (score 4):

One way I found to do it without programming is to make the textfield background transparent, then place a Round Rect Button behind it. Make sure to change the button settings to disable it and uncheck the `Disable adjusts image` checkbox.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check out my library called [DCKit](https://github.com/andrew8712/DCKit).

You'd be able to make a rounded corner text view (as well as text field/button/plain `UIView`) from the `Interface Builder` directly:

[image: DCKit: bordered UITextView]

It also has many other useful features, such as text fields with validation, controls with borders, dashed borders, circle and hairline views etc.

Answer (score 4):

I know there are already a lot of answers to this one, but I didn't really find any of them sufficient (at least in Swift).  I wanted a solution that provided the same exact border as a UITextField (not an approximated one that looks sort of like it looks right now, but one that looks exactly like it and will always look exactly like it).  I needed to use a UITextField to back the UITextView for the background, but didn't want to have to create that separately every time.

The solution below is a UITextView that supplies it's own UITextField for the border.  This is a trimmed down version of my full solution (which adds "placeholder" support to the UITextView in a similar way) and was posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36561236/1227119

```
// This class implements a UITextView that has a UITextField behind it, where the 
// UITextField provides the border.
//
class TextView : UITextView, UITextViewDelegate
{
    var textField = TextField();

    required init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("This class doesn't support NSCoding.")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer);

        self.delegate = self;

        // Create a background TextField with clear (invisible) text and disabled
        self.textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;
        self.textField.textColor = UIColor.clearColor();
        self.textField.userInteractionEnabled = false;

        self.addSubview(textField);
        self.sendSubviewToBack(textField);
    }

    convenience init()
    {
        self.init(frame: CGRectZero, textContainer: nil)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        // Do not scroll the background textView
        self.textField.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.contentOffset.y, self.frame.width, self.frame.height);
    }

    // UITextViewDelegate - Note: If you replace delegate, your delegate must call this
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
    {
        // Do not scroll the background textView
        self.textField.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.contentOffset.y, self.frame.width, self.frame.height);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a great background image that is identical to the `UITextView` used for sending text messages in iPhone's Messages app. You'll need Adobe Illustrator to get & modify it.
[iphone ui vector elements](http://www.mercuryintermedia.com/blog/index.php/2009/03/iphone-ui-vector-elements)

Answer (score 3):

> One way I found to do it without programming is to make the textfield background transparent, then place a Round Rect Button behind it. Make sure to change the button settings to disable it and uncheck the Disable adjusts image checkbox.

Tried the Quartzcore code and found it caused lag on my old 3G (I use for testing). Not a big issue but if you want to be as inclusive as possible for different ios and hardware I recommend Andrew_L's answer above - or make your own images and apply accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 220, 200, 100)];
  textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
  textView.clipsToBounds = YES;
  [textView.layer setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
  [textView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
  [textView.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
  [textView.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
  [textView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
  [self.view addSubView:textview];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Text Field that doesn't accept any events on top of a Text View like this:

```
CGRect frameRect = descriptionTextField.frame;
frameRect.size.height = 50;
descriptionTextField.frame = frameRect;
descriptionTextView.frame = frameRect;
descriptionTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
descriptionTextField.enabled = NO;
descriptionTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
descriptionTextView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Or just make a text field in interface builder. Then set height in code (since the interface builder wont let you). CGRect frameRect = self.textField.frame; frameRect.size.height = 50; self.textField.frame = frameRect;

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your controller code clean, you can subclass UITextView like below, and change the class name in the Interface Builder.

RoundTextView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface RoundTextView : UITextView
@end
```

RoundTextView.m

```
#import "RoundTextView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@implementation RoundTextView
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.333] CGColor]];
        [self.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.textView.text = self.messagePlaceholderText;
    self.textView.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    self.textView.layer.borderColor = [[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3] CGColor];
    self.textView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
    self.textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.5f;
    self.textView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.textView.textColor = [[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if (textView == self.tvMessage) {
        // Delete placeholder text
        if ([self.textView.text isEqualToString:self.messagePlaceholderText]) {
            self.textView.text = @"";
            self.textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
    }
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if (textView == self.tvMessage) {
        // Write placeholder text
        if (self.textView.text.length == 0) {
            self.textView.text = self.messagePlaceholderText;
            self.textView.textColor = [[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible. but you can do `UITableView`(grouped) with 1 section and 1 empty cell and use it as a container for your `UITextView`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, and I was also searched for this questions answer. luvieeres' answer is 100% correct and later Rob added some code. That is excellent, but I found a third party in [another questions answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979384/iphone-uitextview-should-look-like-a-uitextfield) which seems very helpful to me. I was not only searched for similar look of `UITextField` over `UITextView`, I was also searched for multiline support. [ChatInputSample](https://github.com/alekperov/ChatInputSample) satisfied both. Thats why I think this third party might be helpful to others. Also thanks to Timur, he mentioned this open source in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030945/multi-line-textfield-similar-to-sms-and-or-done-button-in-uitextview/13221201#comment18413323_13221201).

Answer (score 0):

In iOS7 the following matches UITextField border perfectly (to my eye at least):

```
textField.layer.borderColor = [[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor];
textField.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
textField.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

There is no need to import anything special.

Thanks to @uvieere and @hanumanDev whose answers go me almost there :)

Answer (score -1):

How about just:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 32)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[self addSubview:textField];
```

Comment: question is about textview.

Comment: Sorry - trigger happy stack response. Would be interested to know why they couldn't just use a `UITextField` with `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO`.

Comment: Textfield doesn't support multiple lines