# how to place a oval shaped UITextField

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

How to change the UITextField to oval shape ?

[link](http://www.adrive.com/public/67db0147f5e5e5a56f4d20b4d39d44ac7293588ceb06477bac70637184e2dac3.html) shows a screenshot of that

Comment: Did you mean round rect as oval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean Round Rect as oval then try this

```
theTextField.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
```

Edit

See this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824463/how-to-style-uitextview-to-like-rounded-rect-text-field).here they have created the round rect text field using quartz core framework.

All the best.

Comment: ya. I tried this but the ends are not in this shape [____] . .i want the shape to be (____)

Comment: If you created the text field by interface builder and set property of border as roundrect in inspector window.

Comment: No i am actually using a tableview and creating the textboxes via code without IB . .

Comment: I think you can use only the inbuilt border style.

Comment: hmm .. I remember seeing an app from medscape which has a oval shaped box. . . so I thought there should be some way !

Comment: I think you referring to the search bar.

Comment: I just now saw some 15 screen shots of that app where text field is roundrect and search bar is oval.

Comment: thanks for the concern. I have edited my question and added a link which shows the actual screen shot of that app.

Answer (score 1):

i used a image which looks like a oval textbox as a backgroun.

[link](http://icodeblog.com/2010/01/04/uitextfield-a-complete-api-overview/)