# Border around UITextView

Tags: text, uitextfield, uitextview, border, cgrect

How do you add a border around a UITextView (like a UITextField)? I want to allow users to type multiple lines, but unfortunately a UITextField does not support this. Is there an easy way to do this in code or do I need to create one in Photoshop?

Answer (score 74):

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Import the above framework and include these lines in your class where textview is defined.

```
[[self.textview layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
[[self.textview layer] setBorderWidth:2.3];
[[self.textview layer] setCornerRadius:15];
```

Swift solution.

```
self.textview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor              
self.textview.layer.borderWidth = 2.3                
self.textview.layer.cornerRadius = 15
```

Comment: Anyway to set back to the default?

Comment: @lostintranslation just try changing the values of border width and corner radius.

Answer (score 25):

Swift solution:

```
    var textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100))
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

No need to import QuarzCore in iOS8

Answer (score 2):

Solution :

```
contentView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
contentView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a quick search, you'll find several answers. Example:

[How to style UITextview to like Rounded Rect text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824463/how-to-style-uitextview-to-like-rounded-rect-text-field)

Comment: This is no way to post an answer, the link can be broken anytime.