# Border around UITextView is not showing up

Tags: iphone

I am trying to add border around UITextView by using

```
 self.textView.layer.borderWidth = 1;

  self.textView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor brownColor] CGColor];
```

but it is not showing up. If anyone can help me with why it is not showing up. Eventhough i have added Quartz framework. But still is not showing up.

```
#import "uitextviewViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@implementation uitextviewViewController

@synthesize textView;
@synthesize navBar;


- (void)dealloc {

[navBar release];
    [textView release];

[super dealloc];
 }


- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

  UIBarButtonItem * button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                         target:self
                                                                         action:@selector(done:)];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:button];
[button release];

self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame] autorelease];

self.textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];

self.textView.delegate = self;

self.textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];

self.textView.layer.borderWidth = 1;

self.textView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor brownColor] CGColor];

self.textView.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;

self.textView.text = @"This is UITextView\n\nThis is UITextView\n\nThis is UITextView\n\nThis is UITextView\n\nThis is UITextView."; 

self.textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview: self.textView]; 

}
```

I will appreciate help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style UITextview to like Rounded Rect text field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824463/how-to-style-uitextview-to-like-rounded-rect-text-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, use this.

Modify it as you'd like.

**UITextFieldWrapper.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITextFieldWrapper : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak, readonly) UITextField * textField;

@end
```

**UITextFieldWrapper.m**

```
#import "UITextFieldWrapper.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UITextFieldWrapper

@synthesize textField = _textField;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.clipsToBounds = YES;

        UITextField * textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 3, frame.size.width - 6, 21)];
        textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self addSubview:textField];
        _textField = textField;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: i changed the color of the border from brown to white now it is showing. But still border is showing only three walls not showing the bottom fourth wall. Any ideas what's missing

Comment: the frame is too large or small. Try 27 for a height.

Comment: @user1120133, If you like my answer would you be so kind as to mark it as 'accepted'? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Following code is use for the give the arc of the UITextbox or other controller for that you need to use the #import  frame work then you can use the following code for the border or arc shape on the control.

```
imgThumb.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
imgThumb.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
imgThumb.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
imgThumb.layer.borderWidth = 0.9;
```

If any query regarding this please comment here...
Happy coding

Comment: still i am not able to see the bottom of the border and not able to scroll eventhough scroll is enabled in my code.

Comment: Actually UITextView supports the content to edit and that not what i want. So i think uiscrollview will solve my purpose. Let me try it.