# How to make a half rounded (Top corner rounded) texview with border?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

How to make a half rounded (Top corner rounded) textview or tableview with the borderwidth and borderColor?[image]

Comment: Refer this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824463/how-to-style-uitextview-to-like-rounded-rect-text-field

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10167334/653513

Comment: @Dee: OP wants to round only certain corners which has to be done by using `bezierPathWithRoundedRect`

Comment: I am using the same as ur links.. But when i am giving the border width and border color, the corner border color is getting chopped off.

Comment: @rokjarc: I used bezierPathWithRoundedRect. but when i am giving border inner part is not rounded. I have attached the screen shot too.

Comment: Try this: textView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f; // this value vary as per your desire
textView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
textView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
textView.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0f; // this value vary as per your desire

Comment: @Dee : I need only certain corners to be rounded not all the corners. As per your comment all the corners will be rounded.

Comment: @Cintu: does bandejapaisa's answer help you? looks promissing.

Comment: I am using the same code. The outer part of the border is rounded and the inner part is still as the square. please check the screen shot in my question.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't perfect, but you can work from this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/CoreAnimation.h>
```

(and also link to QuartzCore.framework in your project), then..

```
self.textView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
self.textView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0f;

UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.textView.bounds 
                                               byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(7.0, 7.0)];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.textView.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
self.textView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
[maskLayer release];
```

Comment: I am using the same code.But still it is not perfectly rounded. Please see the screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

First remove all code that would generate a border (xib or layer.borderWidth) and them use this method below that I created in a UIView Category:

```
#import "UIView+RoundedCorners.h"

@implementation UIView (RoundedCorners)

#pragma mark - Public

- (void)addBorderWithRoundedCorners:(UIRectCorner)roundedCorners radius:(CGFloat)radius color:(UIColor *)color
{
    self.clipsToBounds = NO;
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds    byRoundingCorners:roundedCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    maskLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;
    maskLayer.strokeColor = color.CGColor;
    maskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

    [self.layer addSublayer:maskLayer];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

i think use bellow code

```
    [yourTextView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
    [yourTextView.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
    [yourTextView.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
    [yourTextView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

also use yourTableView insted of yourTextView

Comment: No i need only the top corners rounded with some pixels border.