# Fit uitextview within custom shape

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Is there a way to set a UITextView within a custom shape that isn't a square. Basically I want the text to fit within a circle.

I managed to make a circle border around the text using this answer...

[How to style UITextview to like Rounded Rect text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824463/how-to-style-uitextview-to-like-rounded-rect-text-field)

But the text stays within a square and any text under the border gets cut off.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a UITextKit ([a very good tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial)).

Probably you will have something like:

```
UIBezierPath* exclusionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:yourTextView.bounds];
exclusionPath = [exclusionPath bezierPathByReversingPath];
yourTextView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[exclusionPath];
```