# UITextField border isn't clipping

Tags: swift, uiview, uitextfield, border

<sub>I'm almost sure this question has been asked before, but I searched for almost an hour and didn't find anything</sub>

This is my code:

```
textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
textField.layer.borderWidth = 0.9
textField.placeholder = "border is 0.9 clip is false"
textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
```

[image]

<sub>Doesn't matter if set `textField.clipsToBounds` to `true` or `false`, the borders won't be rounded. However if I change the background color, it will fill it as it has a **rounded** border, see the image below</sub>.

[image]

<sub>if you **zoom in**, you'll see that the it doesn't fill the corners completely</sub>

If I set `textField.layer.borderWidth = 0.1` then I would have a nice roundedRect, but they border would then have to be a thin line. See the image below:
[image]

<sub>again setting `clipToBounds = true` won't make any difference.</sub>

**EDIT:**

So the answer is to do `textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5`. But then I wonder what is the `UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect` doing then?!

Comment: To make borders rounded use cornerRadius property  `textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5`. I think you misunderstood clipToBounds property. See more [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824463/how-to-style-uitextview-to-like-rounded-rect-text-field)

Comment: @Jurasic that was it! so what is does the `UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect` doing?!!

Answer (score 3):

Try `textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5`

`cornerRadius` - the radius to use when drawing rounded corners for the layer’s background. Animatable.

`var cornerRadius: CGFloat { get set }`

> Setting the radius to a value greater than 0.0 causes the layer to
>   begin drawing rounded corners on its background. By default, the
>   corner radius does not apply to the image in the layer’s contents
>   property; it applies only to the background color and border of the
>   layer. However, setting the masksToBounds property to true causes the
>   content to be clipped to the rounded corners.
>
> The default value of this property is 0.0.

Update:

> But then I wonder what is the UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect doing then?

Basically the same thing but with default radius. Maybe it was overwritten somewhere. Check out your IB properties, in Attribute Inspector, Border Style property:

[image]

Comment: What does roundedrect do then?

Comment: I'm doing it programmatically.