# TextView Placeholder in ios objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7

i am using textview in iOS application but i am facing some problem when i am set placeholder in my textview the text not hide when click in textview so can any here who work placeholder in textview

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: Just check it first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835576/how-to-add-placeholder-text-in-uitextview-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: You have to play with TextView Delegate to hide the text when click in textview...

Comment: UITextView doesnot have a placeholder property by default. You need to handle it from your code. Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert placeholder in UITextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038876/how-to-insert-placeholder-in-uitextview)

Comment: https://github.com/devxoul/UITextView-Placeholder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use textView delegate methods to manage placeholder text programatically

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@"myPlaceHolderText"])       
    {
     textView.text = @"";
    }
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        textView.text = @"myPlaceHolderText";
    }
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE: There isn't any inbuilt function for placeholder in textviews like textfields.**

create an `IBOutlet` to your `textView` in `.h` file like below

[image]

and add `<UITextViewDelegate>` like below

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *mytextView;


@end
```

then in your `.m` file, implement `textview` `delegate` methods like below.

[image]

and if you want some addition, try following method also with above code

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSString *mtvt = textView.text;
    if ([mtvt isEqualToString:@""]) {
        self.mytextView.text = @"Your message here";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try This

1.Create a label and show or hide

```
-(void)viewdidLoad
{
   UILabel*placeHolderLabel = [UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,30)];
   placeHolderLabel.text = @"PlaceHolderText";
   placeHolderLabel.textColour = [UIColour lightGrayColor]; 
   [yourTextView addSubView:placeHolderLabel];
}

//2.TextViewDelegate

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    placeHolderLabel.hidden = YES;
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        placeHolderLabel.hidden = NO;
    }
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create placeholder in UITextView but you can generate effect like place holder by this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    commentTxtView.text = @"Comment";
    commentTxtView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    commentTxtView.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL) textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    commentTxtView.text = @"";
    commentTxtView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return YES;
}

-(void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(commentTxtView.text.length == 0){
        commentTxtView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        commentTxtView.text = @"Comment";
        [commentTxtView resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

-(void) textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(commentTxtView.text.length == 0){
        commentTxtView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        commentTxtView.text = @"Comment";
        [commentTxtView resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

**OR you can add label in textview just like**

```
lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0,textView.frame.size.width - 10.0, 34.0)];


[lbl setText:kDescriptionPlaceholder];
[lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[lbl setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
textView.delegate = self;

[textView addSubview:lbl];
```

and set

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *) textView
{
     if (![textView hasText]) {
         lbl.hidden = NO;
     }
}

- (void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(![textView hasText]) {
       lbl.hidden = NO;
    }
    else{
       lbl.hidden = YES;
    }  
}
```