# How to set limit size for UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview, limit, ios6

I need to help for showing limited text in UITextView

Currently i get text from server which is more than 1000 characters.But i need to display only 250 characters and ... at the end in UItextView.Also I have disable edit more in UITextView. So what's the best way to implement this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can register for `UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification` and trim the string received only to 250 characters if it is greater than 250 characters. You can disable editing the text view from IB.

Comment: can you give some example please?

Comment: I don't have access to MAC right now.. so can't give you code... This notification is fired just after the text in textview changes so you can change it just after that, it pretty basic stuff.

Comment: i have tried but it's not called http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview

Comment: placeholder is something else... what are you trying to do...?

Comment: i get the txt from server and i just place the text like placeTxt.text = [listDict objectForKey:@"desc"];

Comment: before setting the text you can check its length and truncate it if it's greater than 250 character, and  why did you give me the link to the placeholder question...?

Comment: just for implementation like the link for notification

Answer (score 0):

You can do like as  :

```
   UITextView *your_txtView;

if ([YourServerString length]>=250) {


    YourServerString = [[YourServerString substringToIndex:249] stringByAppendingString:@"..."];



}
your_txtView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
your_txtView.text = YourServerString;
```