# Programe breakdown when make the delegate itself

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to add UITextView the function of Placeholder, so I do like this:

```
@interface UIPlaceholderTextView : UITextView <UITextViewDelegate>
{
    UILabel *placeholderLabel;
}
```

And when the text changed in the UITextView, the method is called:

```
#pragma UITextViewDelegate
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView.text.length==0)
    {
        placeholderLabel.hidden=false;
    }
    else
    {
        placeholderLabel.hidden=true;
    }

}
```

In the IOS simulator 6.1 everything is ok. But the programe breakdown when I ran in IOS simulator 5.1, and I find the problem happens here :

```
self.delegate = self;
```

It seems that it is not appropriate to make delegate itself. But I don not know the exact reason , and what is the right way to do?

Comment: if you check your code in iOS6 < then label not hide ??

Comment: did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview

Comment: @iPatel it is not because of the function of placeholder that lead to the breakdown, but I make the delegate itself (self.delegate = self) that cause the breakdown.

Comment: why self.delegate? if you are using UITextview then declare the variable and make that variable.delegate = self;

Comment: I suspect you've set `use Autolayout` for your project ?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you assign the delegate to itself? I put it in the initWithFrame and it just worked fine (even with iOS 5.1 deployment target)