# Implementing custom textView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, quartz-graphics

I want to improve a [super cool text view with placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview) and add to it super cool frame like textField has. To do it you simply need to add this code to your `awakeFromNib` method:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    if (self.editable) {
        CALayer *selfLayer = self.layer;
        UIImage *stretchableImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TextView"];
        selfLayer.contents = (id)stretchableImage.CGImage;
        selfLayer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale; // Needed for the retina display, otherwise our image will not be scaled properly.
        selfLayer.contentsCenter = CGRectMake(0.5, 0.5, 1.0/stretchableImage.size.width,1.0/stretchableImage.size.height);

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
}
```

The problem is if you add this `if()` to the above mentioned `placeholderTextView`'s `awakeFromNib` the `drawRect` method of the `placeholderTextView` does not getting called! WHY ? Is it because of accessing layer property of this view? Please guide me through this graphics stuff..!

Comment: While not an answer to your exact question, have you tried adding `[self setNeedsDisplay]` at the end of awakeFromNib?  That will force a `drawRect` call.

Comment: hmm `setNeedsDisplay` really forced the `drawRect` to be called but...nothing happened ) oh , one should really have good understanding of how ios graphics works before using some advanced drawing..