# Compare Placeholder Text in text field

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have set the placeholder text(e.g. Under 18s) of a text field(homeTeam) in storyboard. Now i want to check the condition something like below.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *) textField
{
    if ([_homeTeam.text isEqualToString:@"e.g. Under 18s"]) { // e.g. Under18s
        [_homeTeam setPlaceholder:@""];
    }
}
```

But the condition is never getting true. What am i missing here?  _homeTeam.text is blank when i used NSlog to trace. Why is it so?

Please suggest.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview

Comment: What is the use of setting Place holder to @"" inside the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` ? When you type a character in the text field it'll automatically hide the place holder. So what are you trying to do with this code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `if` condition, it should be `_homeTeam.placeholder` not `_homeTeam.text` because you set  **placeholder** text not a text of `UITextField`.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *) textField
{
    if ([_homeTeam.placeholder isEqualToString:@"e.g. Under 18s"]) { // e.g. Under18s
        [_homeTeam setPlaceholder:@""];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to compare against the `placeholder` property, not `text` (which is input by the user).

Also, I would instead refer to `textField` (instead of `_homeTeam` directly, as you might add other text fields later), as such:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *) textField
{
    if ([textField.placeholder isEqualToString:@"e.g. Under 18s"]) { // e.g. Under18s
        [textField setPlaceholder:@""];
    }
}
```