# Text sent to UITextView text now smaller than the 17 Placeholder text in UIBuilder

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, text-size

IOS 6, iPhone.

I have a UITextView with placeholder text set at Helvetica 17.0.

I send text to the UITextView which is displayed in the same size font.

Just after I was trying to change the colour of one of the placeholder words in UIBuilder, the text of the text sent to the UITextView has become very small. I now cannot seem to display the sent text in the same size font as set in UIBuilder as it used to be. I have not changed any code. What did I do? Any help please.

`_conditionTextView.text = messageText;`

Additional - I changed the UIBuilder "Text" section back to plain and it reverted to as it was. I then changed it back to attributed and it remain good. After changing a placeholder word colour to blue, it did as described above. I absolutely don't need the word blue, so for now I will leave it black. Thanks anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview 
refer this link

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the `text` property, set the `attributedText` property.

Comment: Thanks,But it seems that when there is a colour change to the "attributed text" section in UIBuilder, it causes the sent text to ignore the UIBuilder and use a very small font size. At the moment I will have to use the "plain" text section, this works well. Thanks.