# Unable to calculate height of text area in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextview

I am using the ios library UIPlaceHolderTextView in my application: https://github.com/JohnnyZeng/UIPlaceHolderTextView which is linked to the following question:

[Placeholder in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview)

The library itself is working fine, however, I need to calculate the height of the area after the user has entered text, and unfortunately, I am always getting a value of 0.00000 despite the fact that the text area contains text.  Why is this?  Here is my relevant code:

```
//self.textView is a reference to a UIPlaceHolderTextView object, and text is its attribute

self.textView.text = @"Text that the user has entered, and can be of any length";
    float height = MIN(175, [self.textView.attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.textView.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:NULL].size.height);

NSLog(@"textview height is: %f", self.textView.frame.origin.y);
NSLog(@"textview height is: %f", self.textView.frame.size.height);
```

The output in both lines are 0.00000.  Can anyone see why this is happening?  My guess is that the problem lies in the expression `self.textView.attributedText`, but not sure if I'm correct, and if so, what I should do instead.

Comment: ...and what the `NSLog(@"%f", height);` would say...? because it seems that ivar has the calculated height only in your code fragment, the actual `self.textView` does not.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: My output is 0.00000.  How would I rectify the situation as you've pointed out?

Comment: Why would we expect self.textView.frame.size.height to change if you never show code like self.textView.frame.size.height = height?

Comment: I'm not setting the value of self.textView.frame.size.height anywhere.  I'm trying to determine the value of it based on the text that the user has entered.

Comment: Obvious first question from Mr. Obvious: is `self.textView` definitely not `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning

```
`self.textView.text = @"Text that the user has entered, and can be of any length";`
```

and calculating heightfor `self.textView.attributedText` which is nil i guess please do appropriate changes. It should work.

To make is work you should assign value to self.textView.attributedText

Comment: that should be okay, because the `attributedText` will be auto-populated from the `text`, `font`, `textColor`, `textAlignment`, ect... values, and vica-versa, as the docs says here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView

Answer (score 0):

```
Use a local textview of same width as real textview and set the same text with sizeToFit property.it will be returned in correct frame.

 UITextView *tv = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ScreenWidth, 50)];

    //whatever alignment of real text view you have set
    tv.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
        tv.text= @"Text that the user has entered, and can be of any length";
    [tv sizeToFit];

    float height  =  tv.frame.size.height;
```