# UITextView in IOS7 need to know about placeholder

Tags: ios7

IOS 7 UITextView, is there any way to show placeholder in IOS 7 UITextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native functionality, but You can make your own class,

See this ans

[Placeholder in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview)