# How to set UITextField text custom position and enter new line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `TextField` in `350 X 93` size and I have set the `control` of the `TextField` to vertical up. But I have an issue that the text become in the top too much which it looks weird. How I can set that text programmatically 10 pixel down? "Comment in the picture"

Also another issue how I can set the text to enter a new line after it exceed 100 character? because it won't enter a new line after the `TextField` box reach the end

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address the second question, for multi-line input use [`UITextView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html) instead of [`UITextField`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html). The `textContainerInset` property might be useful. Note that `UITextView` has no facility for showing placeholder text.

Comment: I have searched a lot and I think there is no way of making that after comparing `UITextView` and `UITextFied` ... Thanks.

Comment: Don’t give up! Designers and product managers will not be impressed. Consider using more views, such as separate `UIView`s just to draw the grey boxes, and/or a `UILabel` for the placeholder text that is hidden and shown as necessary.

Comment: I didn't give up... After you told me about `UITextView` missing placeholder feature I searched about it and I found my solution how to do it in this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/10201671/1104515  easiest way. Thanks :)