# IOS/Xcode: Is there a way to add a placeholder to a UITextView created with storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uitextview, placeholder

There seem to be many, albeit, cumbersome [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview) to add a placeholder to a UITextView created programmatically.

Are there any ways to add one to a UITextView created in Storyboards?

I have lots of these in storyboards and would rather not have to recreate them all in code.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: there are two ways: first, you can add a label overlay uitextView, but you also need to change the label's visibility when textView's content changes. another way, you can implement your own textView, and have a placeholder property. then you can set the property at User Defined Runtime Attributes(but the storyboard preview won't show this)

Comment: is the code for this posted anywhere?  Where would I place the needed methods.  In view did load?  Or if there is a textview in the storyboard how would I get the controller to know anything about it?

Comment: in the first way, you can watch textView's content changes at `textViewDidChange` delegate method.

Comment: duplicate with [placeholder in uitextview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview)