# How to add placeholder in UITextField?

Tags: objective-c

```
- (IBAction)segueBut:(id)sender {
    if(_textField.text.length>0&& _textField1.text.length>0 && [_textField1.text isEqual:@"zeeshan"])
    {
        NSString *textoftextfield=_textField.text;
        [ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textoftextfield forKey:@"Name"];
        NSString *textoftextfield1=_textField1.text;
        [ [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textoftextfield1 forKey:@"Password"];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueidentifier" sender:self];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Insert Username and password Textfield is empty"   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        alert.delegate=self;
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Placeholder in UITextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview)

Comment: @I'L'I Question is for UITextFiled not for UITextView

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: explain your requirement, otherwise it will be downvoted & get deleted

Answer (score 1):

Use property placeholder of text field and pass string.

```
_textField.placeholder = @"Enter Something";
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntactic sugar way:

```
_textField.placeholder = @"your text here";
```

Or the normal way:

```
[_textField setPlaceholder:@"your text here"];
```