# Alternative for place holder in textView

Tags: ios, textview

I have used two `delegate` methods to create a place holder for textView.

**Code:**

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{

    if([Description.text isEqualToString:@"Description of home"]&&[Description.font isEqual:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18]])
    {
        Description.text=nil;
    }
    if([Display.text isEqualToString:@"Display"]&&[Display.font isEqual:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18]])
    {
        Display.text=nil;
    }
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{

    if ([Description.text isEqualToString:@""]) // Description is textViewObject
    {
        Description.text=@"Description of home";
        Description.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18];
    }


    if ([Display.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        Display.text=@"Display";   // Display is textViewObject
        Display.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18];
    }
    return YES;
}
@end
```

This is working correct. But **problem** is that when I am clicking on any textView, the text is getting `nil` from all textView. This is because I have connected all textView to delegate.

I want that text should disappear on particular textView only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Placeholder in UITextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview)

Comment: I think the best way to add placeholder support to UITextView is to subclass it, like this: [YXTextView](https://github.com/yixia-team/YXTextView).

Comment: You need to subclass UITextView and add a label as a subview. You will drive yourself crazy doing it this way through delegate methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add conditions in the delegate methods like this :

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
if(textView == yourTextView1)
{
    //your code for perticular textView1
}
 else if(textView == yourTextView2)
{
    //your code for perticular textView2
}

  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate each of your `UITextViews` in some way.

If you are to have a small number of `UITextViews` on the screen, then you should save each of your UItextViews as a property. Check out this youtube video on [creating IBOutlets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0drKymvo09o)

Then just name your `UITextViews` in order: textView1, textView2 etc...

Then in your delegate methods, you can check if the textView being passed in the method is equal to the property you want to delete text from.

```
if (textView == self.textView1) {
    //delete text
} else {
    //do nothing or something else
}
```

Answer (score -1):

check if the delegate is operating on the wanted `UITextView`:

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{

    if(textView == Description && [Description.text isEqualToString:@"Description of home"]&&[Description.font isEqual:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18]])
    {
        Description.text=nil;
    }
    if(textView==Display && [Display.text isEqualToString:@"Display"]&&[Display.font isEqual:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18]])
    {
        Display.text=nil;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest solution by @
CmKndy for this problem is https://stackoverflow.com/a/10201671/3633534

use `UITextViewDelegate` delegate in your class and add text `@"placeholder text here..."` in your `textView` with `lightGrayColor` to display by default.

**Following code is for place holder in `textView` :**

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@"placeholder text here..."]) {
        textView.text = @"";
        textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //optional
    }
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        textView.text = @"placeholder text here...";
        textView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; //optional
    }
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

**For your question[Update]**

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(textView == Description && [Description.text isEqualToString:@"Description of home"])
    {
        Description.text = @"";
    }
    else if(textView == Display && [Display.text isEqualToString:@"Display"])
    {
        Display.text = @"";
    }
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView == Description && [Description.text isEqualToString:@""]) // Description is textViewObject
    {
        Description.text = @"Description of home";
        Description.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18];
    }
    else if (textView == Display && [Display.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        Display.text = @"Display";   // Display is textViewObject
        Display.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18];
    }
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: You could do this, but it's unconventional. 

Creating an IBOutlet property referencing the UITextView is safer and more predictable than matching strings. You could type something wrong in the "if statement" or in the placeholder field in IB, and it might take more time to debug.

Comment: @Adama,  `(UITextView *)textView`  will always reference to current `textView` and scope is only in defined method, so their is no chance of mistake. `IBOutlet` is different thing, it is for global use to refer any `id`.