# How to add a pre-text(?) to text view?

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm trying to add a text to UITextView to show while no editing and no content. Actually I'm trying to use it to show transparent UITextView. How can I add a pre-text to text view?

Comment: I believe it called "hint". try to serch it, you might find

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is quite the hack you can do:

set the default textView text to your 'pre-text' and the color is grayColor. using the below method:

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView*) textView {

if ([textView textColor] == [UIColor grayColor]) {
    [textView setText:@""];
}

[textView setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

**Swift**

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.textColor == UIColor.grayColor(){
        textView.text = ""
        textView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
}
```

you can then change the text and reset the text color to black color.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a placeholder. It's part of the UITextField properties.
[image: placeholder]