# I want the text to be deleted when I tap on textfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'm making an easy app where I have textFields. When the app starts I have examples in my textfields. I want these text examples to be deleted when users tap on textField. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Instead of setting the `text` property of these fields you should simply set the `placeholder` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set **Placeholder** text in **UITextField**. Whenever, **UITextField** is tapped placeholder text disappears.

Alternatively, you can use following **UITextFieldDelegate** method

**Objective-C**

```
 - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   textField.text = ""
}
```

**Swift**

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
  textField.text = ""
}
```

Comment: Finally an answer that makes sense.

Comment: There is only one problem here: any text would be cleared in your case (when using the `text` instead of the `placeholder` property) as soon as user begins editing. One should at least compare the content to 'initial' content and clear if (and only if) they are a match.

Comment: It's not clear from question what exactly @lucca910 wants to acheive. Whether he wants to delete text every time like in some cases of Passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this underneath your didMoveToView method in youre SpriteKit Game

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, with Event event: UIEvent?) {

for touch in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
       if nodeAtPoint(location) = textField {
          textField.removeFromParent()
            }
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create text field with placeholder.

this link might helps you.

[Placeholder in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview)

Comment: Why are you linking to a question about putting a placeholder in a `UITextView`? This question is about `UITextField`.