# How to use new insertTextPlaceholder of ios 13?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

insertTextPlaceholder is available as of ios 13

I am trying to create a place holder for textview

```
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        msgBox.insertTextPlaceholder(with: CGSize(width: 210, height: 40))
    }
```

I don't see any placeholder created after this code

How can I use it properly?

Comment: What does `insertTextPlaceholder` do? UITextView does not contain this method.

Comment: @VladislavMarkov apparently it does contain

Comment: Do you have a link to this? I think it does not contain. You can see it here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview

Comment: Maybe you have an extension for UITextView. Or you use a subclass of UITextView.

Comment: No, I just use this let msgBox = UITextView() and msgBox.insertTextPlaceholder

Comment: I'm sorry, I see the function. I'm wrong.

Comment: I found it - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/3213953-inserttextplaceholder. It does not have a description and it's an optional function. It's strange ). I will try to find out what it is.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked this question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should not use it right now. Because [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/3213953-inserttextplaceholder) are very poor. And [UITextPlaceholder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextplaceholder) also has no interesting information.

I have not found anything useful about the function. Maybe it is not ready yet.

You should use [Placeholder in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328638/placeholder-in-uitextview).

### What does the function do?

I found that it creates an empty space at the beginning of the `UITextView` with `size` that you pass to it.

1) `UITextField` (white field) without using `insertTextPlaceholder`:
[image]

2) `UITextField` with using `insertTextPlaceholder`:
[image]

### Warning

It causes crashes. For example, if you add this:

```
let placeholder = textView.insertTextPlaceholder(with: CGSize(width: 100, height: 40))
textView.insertText("Test")
```

And type something in `UITextView`, you get this:

> 2020-04-29 14:20:10.264832+0300 StackOverflow[17081:284345] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[NSBigMutableString substringWithRange:]: Range {1,
>   18446744073709551615} out of bounds; string length 5'
>   *** First throw call stack: (...